# jQuery Hide div if value is smaller than

Tags: jquery, html, magento, web

**I have this span:**

```
<span class="price">£260.00</span>
```

**and another another one**

```
<span class="price">£90.00</span>
```

I need to hide the **div** below when the value from span is smaller than **£100.00**.

```
<div id="shipping"></div>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem. I need to know how to do this using **jQuery**.

Comment: Is it possible to you to store the cost numeric value (without the pound sign) in another separate property? e.g `<span class="price" cost-num="260">£260.00</span>`. It will make that easy.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var price = $(".price").text().replace("£","");

if(price < 100)
{
    $("#shipping").hide();
}else{
    $("#shipping").show();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var price = $('span.price'),
        // get float number from span.text() excluding other characters than digits and dot
        priceValue = Number(price.text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")),
        priceLimit = 100,
        shipping = $("#shipping");

    shipping.show(); // by default shipping show

    if (priceValue > priceLimit) {
        // other case shipping hide
        shipping.hide();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/calinsargan/Fp25n/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I try to run this in firebug console log and get this message "Object[Document /checkout/cart/]"

Comment: /checkout/cart/ = a piece of my current link... any idea why i get this?

Comment: Well, insert the snippet in the page template you intend to use. From the URL provided, i think it's Shopping Cart related.

Comment: I did this but still any result. I can't understand why isn't working.

Comment: If you don't have errors in the console, it isn't working because other reasons. What are you trying to achieve?